# Slow JavaScript function, how can I improve it?

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript function that seems to perform really slow.

This function gets called many times within a loop

```
function _matches(el, selectors) {

    var result = selectors.filter(function (selector) {
          return [].indexOf.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), el) !== -1;
    });

    return result.length > 0;
}
```

Here is an example of how this function is called

```
// Vertical Loop
rows.map(function (element, row) {

    if (_matches(element, '.ignore')) {
        // do something A
    }

    if (_matches(element, '.empty')) {
        // do something B
    }

    var cols = element.querySelectorAll("th, td");
    // Horizontal Loop
    return cols.map(function (element, ic) {

        if (_matches(element, '.ignore')) {
            // do something A
        }
        if (_matches(element, '.empty')) {
            // do something B
        }
    });
});
```

I am unsure what the `[].indexOf.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), el)` line does or means so I am not sure how to improve the performance of this function.

Comment: Learning what `[].indexOf.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), el)` does would be the best first step in improving the function. Have you tried breaking it down into its component pieces and looking at how what each part does?

Comment: selectors.filter is looping more than it needs to, selectors.some() would make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're finding all elements in the DOM matching a given selector, then asking whether an element you *already have* appears in that set. This an *extremely* inefficient way to tell if the element you already have matches a given selector.

Just use `element.matches(selector)`.

```
// No:
if (_matches(element, '.ignore')) {
  // do something A
}

// Yes:
if (element.matches('.ignore')) {
  // do something A
}
```

Comment: Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches for further information.

The `_matches()` function in your example duplicates, poorly, an existing language feature.

Comment: If you're one of the pitiable programmers who must support Internet Explorer well past its presumed death, [use `msMatches()`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=matchesselector).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Assuming that's the case, the MDN article contains a polyfill, which is no more efficient than the existing `_matches` OP has provided. However the polyfill is only relevant to IE users, everybody else gets the native `element.matches`.

Comment: Well...You're out of luck for IE <9, and you're not using something like polyfills, Babel, Webpack etc. Yeah, what that heretical simian said!

Comment: Yeah, I read caniuse a bit closer and apparently it's available as `msMatches` back to IE9. I'm stuck on a project that has to support IE11 right now so it's close to home. I just wanted to give warning to those of us poor schmucks stuck supporting it :).